# how to perform a background job rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, task

I've got a campaign table with a start date and end date.  How do I go about running a daily task that would basically flip a boolean 'active' value in the table from true to false when the current date is greater than the end date.

I haven't dealt with any background tasks, just wondering how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [rake task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) to execute the rails code and either straight cron / crontab to run / schedule the task on the server, or checkout [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) which handles setting up cron jobs for you.

Depending on what your hosting / deploy set up is there's a variety of ways to automate this, but need more detail in your question for that.